Solr causes problem with and without hashtag in command line parameter
Hello I've some problem using solr.
In command line
solr.cmd post -c my_core my_path
the error is
PostTool: WARNING: Response: <p>   Searching for Solr?<br/>   You must type the correct path.<br/>   Solr will respond. </p>
When using
solr.cmd post -c #/my_core my_path
other error
PostTool: WARNING: IOException while posting data: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server PostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Incomplete output stream ERROR: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/: Expected mime type in [application/vnd.apache.solr.javabin, application/octet-stream] but got text/html. <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/> <title>Error 400 La méthode HTTP POST n&apos;&apos;est pas supportée par cette URL</title> </head> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400 La méthode HTTP POST n&apos;&apos;est pas supportée par cette URL</h2> <table> <tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/</td></tr> <tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>400</td></tr> <tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>La méthode HTTP POST n&apos;&apos;est pas supportée par cette URL</td></tr> <tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>LoadAdminUI</td></tr> </table> </body> </html>
So, the #/ seems to be needed for some command, but not for other. What is the problem ?
In the browser, hashtag is needed
http://localhost:8983/solr ==> hashtag added at he end automatically http://localhost:8983/solr/#
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core ==> go to the error
Searching for Solr?
You must type the correct path.
Solr will respond.
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/geci/core-overview ==> OK

from a linux cmd-line, the # will be interpreted as the comment character. To illustrate, try echo hello # comment. Now try echo "hello # comment". You'll need to escape any # char (and other shell meta chars ($,[,]{,},&,| (and possibly others)) for proper interpretation. '#' and \# and "#" are all "escaped" # chars. Not sure what the case is for Windows cmd lines, REM and ?? something else are the comment chars. Good luck.

In the future, be sure to include a tag to focus on the environment your cmd-line is running: at least [unix] OR [linux] AND [shell] OR [bash] OR [zsh] OR [ksh] or a few really obscure others. (one OS and one shell, or you'll get people mad at you). Also read the text/description/rules for each tag that you include by mouse-hovering on the tag.

A # in an URL is an anchor, and is not sent to the server - the server would never receive the # part when you're entering the URL in your browser. The part after # is only used by the javascript interface to know what state it should use as its initial state.

Solr's error messages are not really appropriate.
It could be: indexing of the pdf file impossible because not configured in place of Searching for Solr? You must type the correct path. Solr will respond.
The error came from a bad configuration for the server\solr\my_core\conf\solrconfig.xml file, which is created with minimal properties when creating a new core.
I took the sample file \sample_techproducts_configs\conf\solrconfig.xml and this time, the indexing works very well, after removing the QueryElevationComponent section.
